# Would removing user who created a scheduled query on BigQuery break said query?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Would removing a user from our GCP project who was the original creator of scheduler queries break them?

Don't seem to find an obvious answer and would like to know before we proceed.

If it does we can go through all scheduled queries and update credentials but would like to avoid this if possible.

Comment: In this case, when you're removing the user from project, the call to Bigquery API will be authenticated but not authorized to run scheduled query, I believe you have to update credentials for the next user or service account who is granted to work with Bigquery objects inside this project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do explain a bit more, extending my comment and giving some useful links.

According to GCP [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries#quotas):

> A scheduled query is executed with the creator's credentials and
>   project, as if you were executing the query yourself.

The above mentioned confirms the principle of the GCP visitor's [authentication](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication) strategy. The Google identities like users and service accounts must be entitled first and then authorized via [IAM](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs) access center.

Therefore, *quoting* my comment: when you're removing the user from project, the call to [*Bigquery API*](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest) will be authenticated but not authorized to run scheduled query, I believe you have to update credentials for the next user or service account who is granted to work with Bigquery objects inside this project.

Comment: does this mean that all scheduled queries will need to be recreated by another user? Or is there a way to transfer ownership of the existing scheduled queries?