# User account does not exist in GCP IAM, however still the scheduled queries created by the user executing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam

I have couple of scheduled queries in GCP which are created by the user A. The user A has left the company, her account is not found from the GCP IAM but available in the x-domain.co directory. I see the queries are everyday running successfully!

Is this a normal behaviour?

I followed the below question already, as per this it is not possible!
[Would removing user who created a scheduled query on BigQuery break said query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60544304/would-removing-user-who-created-a-scheduled-query-on-bigquery-break-said-query)

Comment: My bad! User is part of some group in GCP IAM & Admin, and the group does have sufficient roles to execute the queries.

Comment: Post that as the answer. Your issue is an often-overlooked vulnerability.

Answer (score 2):

Answer:

Even though the users may not be in the result of the below command,

```
gcloud projects get-iam-policy <project_id> \
--flatten="bindings[].members" \
--format="value(bindings.members)" \
--sort-by=bindings.members | uniq
```

When the users are part of some Groups in GCP IAM & Admin, and if that Group has sufficient resource access roles assigned, it allows them to create and schedule the big queries in GCP.